# Storing elements of one list, in another list - by reference - in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, reference

I just thought I'd jot this down now that I've seen it - it would be nice to get a confirmation on this behavior; I did see [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference), but I'm not sure how to interpret it in this context.

Let's say we have these two arrays/lists:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [-1, a, -100, a[2], -1]
```

The interpreter initially sees them as:

```
>>> print(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print(b)
[-1, [1, 2, 3, 4], -100, 3, -1]
```

Now let's change `a[2]`, and see what happens:

```
>>> print(a)
[1, 2, 55, 4]
>>> print(b)
[-1, [1, 2, 55, 4], -100, 3, -1]
```

So, wherever list `b` has a reference to the *list* `a`, the value has been updated - but wherever `b` was initialized with (a reference to?) an *element from* list `a`, it seems that Python expanded the value at initialization time, and thus stored the element by value (not by reference), so it's value obviously doesn't update.

Basically, I found a use case, where it would be convenient to be able to define e.g. `b = [-1 a[2] -1]`, and then update `a[2]`, and be able to count that the latest value of `a[2]` will be emitted when getting the value of (in this case) `b[1]`. Is there a way to do that in Python, without having to do `b = [-1 a -1]`, and then reading `b[1][2]` (I'd like to get the value of `a[2]` just by using `b[1]`)?

Answer (score 2):

`a` is a reference to a mutable list.  So, when you say:

```
a[2] = 55
```

you are calling `__setitem__` on the list which *sets an item in the list*.  `list.__setitem__` doesn't make any attempt to mutate the item that used to be stored in the second index.  It simply replaces that reference with a new one.

On the other side, `x = a[2]` calls `__getitem__` which just creates a new reference to the object stored at that index in the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = [1000,2000,3000,4000]
>>> sys.getrefcount(a[2])
2
>>> b = [-1, a, -100, a[2], -1]
>>> a is b[1]   # b[1] and `a` are actually two variables pointing to the same object
True
#[1000,2000,3000,4000] can be accessed or modified by either `a` or `b[1]`
>>> sys.getrefcount(a)  
3

>>> sys.getrefcount(a[2])
3
```

Now there are total 3 references to the object 3000 in memory(`a[2]`,`b[-2]`  and shell itself), but as integers are immutable so if you change of modify `a[2]` it'll simply remove one reference from the object 3000, But `b[-2]` will still point to the same object in memory and `a[2]` will now point to some newly assigned object.

```
>>> id(a[2]),id(b[-2])
(150561920, 150561920)
>>> a[-2] = 5
>>> id(a[2]),id(b[-2])  #b still points to the same object
(148751024, 150561920)
>>> sys.getrefcount(b[-2])
2
```

If the item at `a[2]` is a mutable object, say `list`:

```
>>> a = [1000,2000, [2] , 4000]
>>> b = [-1, a, -100, a[2], -1]
>>> a[2] += [5]     # we can modify [2] from from either a[2] or b[-2]
>>> b[-2]+= [10]    # `+=` , `list.extend`, `list.append` changes the list in-place
>>> a[2] is b[-2]   #both still points to the same object as lists are mutable
True
>>> a
[1000, 2000, [2, 5, 10], 4000]
>>> b
[-1, [1000, 2000, [2, 5, 10], 4000], -100, [2, 5, 10], -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem of accessing sublists by index of the outer list, you can use something like:

```
class RecursiveList(list):
    def getitem(self, index, recurse=True):
        if not recurse:
            return self[index]
        else:
            return list(RecursiveList.flatten(self))[index]

    @staticmethod
    def flatten(l):
        for item in l:
            if hasattr(item, "__iter__"):
               for v in RecursiveList.flatten(item):
                   yield v
            else:
               yield item
```

For the exact behaviour you ask for, add the following:

```
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.getitem(i, true)
```

Note, this will probably break if you try to use slices.